How to make sure that my API is only accessed by my csr frontend
I am making an API using django and drf. My problem is my frontend devs doesn't want to have a ssr application, so I must have a way to protect my API so if a user figures out an endpoint, they can't use it. in other words, I want to make sure that only my csr frontend can use my API.
I researched a bit and found things like API gateways and proxy backend. But it doesn't help in my problem. I thought of CORS. But each user got they're own ip address and they still can use curl.
I am working on least privilege principle and already use jwt tokens.

The short answer is "you can't". That's simply how the Internet - and any distributed-system in-general, works: never trust the client.

"so I must have a way to protect my API so if a user figures out an endpoint, they can't use it." - What are you afraid of?

you can let your users authenticate and only accept requests from authenticated users. But you cannot limit it to an application.

I mean, we could discuss the merits of device-attestation and a secure-bootchain that includes userland applications - but I don't want people thinking that's a good idea.
